# In angr, how to Load and Analyze a binary file that only contain a function instructions

Tags: binary

I have some binary files, each of them contain instructions of a function, (may be a little more in the end). The begining of the file also is the start point of the function.

This files were extracted from a ELF file.The platform is arm64.

So, how to load and analyze this file using angr?
I upload a sample file here: xfrank.pythonanywhere.com/bin

---

The original target:

Every function has a "switch case statement", the target is to get all intergers of the case expression.

Example(C code):

```
void func1(int cmd){
    switch (cmd) {
    case 1:
        xxxx
        break;
    case 10:
        yyyy;
        break;
    }
}
```

Result: 1,10

Comment: Can you share some of these binary files with us?

Comment: I upload a sample file here: http://xfrank.pythonanywhere.com/bin

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps I would normally do:

- Load the binary in angr.
- Build a CFG.
- For each function you care about, first, get a reference of the function (`func = cfg.functions[addr]` or `func = cfg.functions.function(name=the_name)`), and then traverse the graph (`func.graph` or `func.transition_graph`).

Comment: How to load the binary in angr without any 'head' info?

Comment: What's head info? Are you talking about loading binary blobs directly? You can manually specify format facts when loading, like architecture, loading offsets, etc. This is not well-documented currently in angr-docs, but it is documented in the doc-strings of `angr.Project()` and `cle.Loader`.